# Apache Airflow - 1.10 - How to access SQL files durin run

Tags: airflow

TL;DR How do I make it so that assets (SQL files, text files) are reachable by the tasks in my dag

Hello Folks,

I'm running a single node Airflow installation (1.10.12).  I have a dag that uses SQL statements.  For the sake of readability, I'd like to keep these statements in their own SQL file.  So my project looks like so:

```
  MyProject
   - airflow_ftp_DAG.py
   - airflow_ftp_assets (directory)
      - WEX_HH_Upsert_SQL.sql
```

When my dag runs, it complains that it can't find the SQL file.  This is caused by the fact that dag runs it's tasks in different folders (as seen by running `os.getcwd()`)

How do I get my SQL file to be referencable by my tasks?

```
def insert_hh_records(**kwargs):
    key = 'WEX_FILETYPE_HH'
    collated_data_file_path = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key=key)

    sql_path = "airflow_wex_ftp_assets/WEX_HH_Upsert_SQL.sql"
    sql_string = ''

    <!---  Error below --->

    with open(sql_path,"r") as f:
        sql_string = f.read()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was uploading my Dag files as zip files into my dag folder.  Somewhere along the way, it was unzipping them, but not keeping the SQL asset files.  Once I stopped zipping them, the problem went away.